# Ruby regexp should exclude "125af" substrings

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following regexp:

```
/^(\d{1,11})((?:(?:c?o|co?).*)?.*)$/i
```

that matches strings like:

```
125******* or 125co****** or 125CO*******
```

I would like to exclude substrings that begin with:

```
125af***** or 125AF****** or 125f****** or 125AF********
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
^(?>\d{1,11})(?!af|a|f)((?:(?:c?o|co?).*)?.*)$
```

See it [here on regexr](http://regexr.com?31g6i)

I made two changes to your regex:

1. I made the first group [atomic](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) (`(?>\d{1,11})`) by adding the `?>` at the start. This is to avoid backtracking into the already matched digits,
2. I added a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!af|a|f)` , to ensure that there is no af, a or f following. For this to work I need the first group to be atomic, to ensure that it will really look after the last digit ahead. (Otherwise it will backtrack, see the before last digit ahead, think everything is fine and match the rest of the string with the last `.*`)

Comment: For `a(?>bc|b)c` you can say its the same than `a(bc)c`, but for more complex expressions you can't. The thing is: you have a string "abc" and the atomic expression. Your expression will match "a", that obvious. Then it will try the first alternative "bc", that will match too, but then there is a "c" required after the alternation, but the string is completely matched. Normally it would backtrack and try the second alternative, but since it is an atomic group, it will not backtrack, so it fails, since there is no "c" left in the string, that can be matched by the last "c" in the regex.

Comment: Ok, thanks. To get a MatchData object with the number part "125" I modified your regex like so: ^((?>\d{1,11}))(?!af|a|f)((?:(?:c?o|co?).*)?.*)$